# I have a issue in establishing a connection "I send the message but, i did not get a reply"

Tags: python

I am trying to establish a connection in python using package SIMPLE WEBSOCKETSERVER so that chatbot can give reply, but i can send the message but i did not get reply(response) back.

It is my server.py file:

```
from SimpleWebSocketServer import SimpleWebSocketServer, WebSocket
from chatbot import get_response

class ChatServer(WebSocket):

    def handleMessage(self):
        # echo message back to client
        message = self.data
        response = get_response(message)
        self.sendMessage(response)

    def handleConnected(self):
        print(self.address, 'connected')
       # print(" handleConnected ")



    def handleClose(self):
        print(self.address, 'closed')
       # print(" handleClose ")


server = SimpleWebSocketServer('', 8000, ChatServer)
server.serveforever()
```